# remove a element from the list using jquery

Tags: jquery

Im tryiing to remove a element using the Jquery remove method but for some reason the below code does not remove it..

fiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/7RCyX/3/

html

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

js

```
var listitems = $('li')
alert(listitems.length)
var firstitem = listitems.eq[0]
firstitem.remove()
```

Comment: I'd suggest using console.log rather than alert for debugging. It can give you a lot more info in a less annoying way.

Answer (score 1):

[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is a function, which will return the element at the said index

```
var listitems = $('li')
alert(listitems.length)
var firstitem = listitems.eq(0)
firstitem.remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PBUp8/)

Answer (score 1):

You're grabbing the element as a DOM element rather than a jQuery element. Almost, if you did 
firstitem = listitems[0]. As it is your code is triggering a syntax error. Arun P suggests how to fix your `.eq` call so it works.

You might also try these to remove the item:

```
$('li').first().remove()
```

or

```
$('li:first').remove()
```